# Getting rid of zombies in perl

Tags: perl, fork, zombie-process

I have written a server in perl, waiting for tcp connections.
Every time the server receives one, it forks a new child in charge of it and continues listening for another connection.( And so it cannot wait for the SIGCHILD. )
The child does what it is supposed to do and exits, but continues to "live" as a zombie. 
What is the solution please ?

Comment: Have you tried `wait()`/`waitpid()`?

Comment: thanks for your answer el.pescdo
the problem is that waitpid blocks the parent. My parent has something else to do.

Comment: `waitpid (-1, &WNOHANG)` should not block. See below

Answer (score 5):

Set `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';` to have the system handle them for you automatically.

Or set `$SIG{CHLD}`to a subroutine and `waitpid`:

```
use POSIX qw( WNOHANG );

$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    while( ( my $child = waitpid( -1, WNOHANG ) ) > 0 ) {
        print "SIGNAL CHLD $child\n";
    }
};
```

If you really want to understand how it works (of course you do! :), you should read [perlipc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html)

There is also more info [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389400/whats-the-difference-between-various-sigchld-values)

Comment: thank you grebneke. I have been looking for it for a longtime :)