# Perl system function returns -1 even after successful execution

Tags: perl, return, system, return-code

I've got some weird situation going on with a 3rd party perl script. To demonstrate:

```
my $rc = system("tar -C /app/src -xvf /app/package.tar.gz");

if ($rc != 0)
{
   print "Return code: $rc";  
}
```

Running `tar -C /app/src -xvf /app/package.tar.gz` directly on the shell works just fine, `echo $?` shows the exit status `0`. All good.

Also, when running this small perl snippet the return is *always* `-1`. If I try something like:

```
my $rc = system("ls");

if ($rc != 0)
{
   print "Return code: $rc";  
}
```

...the return code will also be `-1`.

I don't have much knowledge in perl, so I wonder what could possibly trigger this behaviour.

The documentation doesn't mention anything in particular regarding this (http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).

---

**Solution:**

Fetching `$!`to get some more details about the error:

```
my $rc = system("tar -C /app/src -xvf /app/package.tar.gz");

if ($rc != 0)
{
   print "Return code: $rc\n";
   print "Reason: $!";  
}
```

Returned:

```
Return code: -1
Reason: No child processes
```

Applying `$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'DEFAULT';` fixed the issue:

```
$SIG{'CHLD'} = 'DEFAULT';

my $rc = system("tar -C /app/src -xvf /app/package.tar.gz");

if ($rc != 0)
{
   print "Return code: $rc\n";
   print "Reason: $!";  
}
```

Some details from:
[What's the difference between various $SIG{CHLD} values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389400/whats-the-difference-between-various-sigchld-values)

Comment: I can imagine issues with the first case but the second one is strange. What system are you on?  Do your Perl programs normally run ok -- or is this the first one you tried? If you redirect output to a file (`system('ls > ls.txt')` or such) do you get the correct file after this?  If you use backticks instead, `my $ret = qx(ls);` what do you get in `$ret`?

Comment: What was the value of `$SIG{CHLD}`? Why wasn't the value change [local](http://p3rl.org/local)ized?

Comment: @choroba what do you mean by "Why wasn't the value change localized?" $SIG{CHLD} was previously undefined, which defaults to `IGNORE` (as far as I understood the documentation).

Comment: Ah, OK. The remaining question is why Perl fails to wait() for the `system`.

Comment: Nice that you dug into it and updated but note that this doesn't at all explain the strange behavior that you report in the second snippet. The fact that installing a signal handler (and to default!) "fixes" it is good diagnostics but there is something seriously off there.

Answer (score 4):

Right in the documentation you linked to (emphasis mine):

> Return value of **-1** indicates a failure to start the program or an error of the wait(2) system call (inspect `$!` for the reason).

Comment: Thank you, sir! I wasn't aware (at all) of `$!`... This gave me some extra details: `No child processes`